# OData v4 filter resource by active user

Tags: odata, odata-v4

I am working on an OData v4 compliant RESTful API, and have a need to filter a collection of tasks based on the assigned user. It would be useful to be able to handle this based on the active user, without having to explicitly refer to the user ID of the assigned user in the filter expression. Take the following request and response as an example:

```
GET /Tasks

{
  "value": [
    {
      "Assignee": "user1"
    },
    {
      "Assignee": "user2"
    },
    {
      "Assignee": "user3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I could do something like `/Tasks?$filter=Assignee eq 'user1'` but this requires that the consumer keep track of who the active user is. Is there some convention to do this in a more generic way? For example: `/Tasks?$filter=Assignee eq $ActiveUser`.

Comment: Just adding a comment not on how to technically achieve this but on whether you want to do it with this URL at all, I would suggest that this behaviour isn't very transparent. I would prefer to see an endpoint like this instead: `GET /CurrentUser/Tasks` which would make it much more explicit

Comment: Hrm, hadn't considered this, but it makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the suggestion!